# Aggregating two rows, SQL

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate

This is an example of what I'm working on

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFfgn.png)

Forgive the picture, I couldn't figure out the table feature

This is my code

```
select o.id order_id, m.id, m.override_pay_amt
from orders o
left join movement_order mo
on o.id = mo.order_id
and mo.company_id = 'TMS'
left join movement m
on mo.movement_id = m.id
and m.company_id ='TMS'
where o.status != 'V' and o.company_id = 'TMS' and (o.id = '6008227' or o.id = '6000006')
order by o.id
```

I can't figure out how to combine order_id 6008227 in to one row.

I've tried:

```
select o.id order_id, m.id, sum(m.override_pay_amt) pay
from orders o
left join movement_order mo
on o.id = mo.order_id
and mo.company_id = 'TMS'
left join movement m
on mo.movement_id = m.id
and m.company_id ='TMS'
where o.status != 'V' and o.company_id = 'TMS' and (o.id = '6008227' or o.id = '6000006')
group by o.id
order by o.id
```

but when I do this, it makes me group by m.id and nothing changes in the table.

What am I missing?

Comment: The SELECT statement is for accessing data. If you want to change the table, you need to use the UPDATE statement.

Comment: Do you mean update the actual movement table or the "table" that my query creates?

Comment: When you say 'combine order_id 6008227 in to one row' it means GROUP BY O.ID and everything else in the `SELECT` other than O.ID should be aggregate functions (like SUM, but not M.ID). If you want to show M.ID and if there are different values of M.ID for any O.ID how would they be combined into one row? If you still want M.ID you can get MIN/MAX/AVG, etc (aggregate) of it.

Comment: @tinazmu that makes a lot of sense. GROUP BY really confuses me, do I always have to group by everything that isn't an aggregate?

Comment: Yes. Group by means only 1 row per unique combination of values for expressions on the group by line (unless they are removed by a `having` clause)

Comment: So this leads to my real question. In my big table, I have 15000 rows, but I also have about 30 duplicate o.id's. The duplicates are where there are more than one m_id associated with the same o_id, how do I get rid of the duplicates? I still want to sum the pay amount, it doesnt matter which m.id gets used as long as the pay is summed. Any thoughts?